# Why is an undefined value of an array of array that typeof returns as "undefined" not considered true by my conditional?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, conditional-statements, typeof

Why does an undefined value of an array of array that typeof returns as "undefined" not considered true by my conditional? Is it something to do with the OR operator or what. It seems like my program is running the inner conditional even though it shouldn't be in the inner conditional.

```
if(typeof elemData !== 'undefined' || typeof rich[elemData.value] !== 'undefined') {

    if(typeof rich[elemData.value]['title'] !== 'undefined') {
        //do something
    }

}
```

program returns the following:

```
> if(typeof rich[elemData.value]['title'] !== 'undefined') {
> 
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

I'm checking if `rich[elemData.value]` is `'undefined'` and it's saying it's not via my conditional. What's going on?

Comment: What does the TypeError have to do with 'considered true'? The equality expression (thought to play a part) *never even executes* because the exception is *thrown first*. The error message explains the problem exactly; break on the exception and verify/fix the incorrect assertions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are ORing your conditions when you need to AND them.

```
if(typeof elemData !== 'undefined' || typeof rich[elemData.value] !== 'undefined') {
```

Should be:

```
if(typeof elemData !== 'undefined' && typeof rich[elemData.value] !== 'undefined') {
```

Comment: This works, but why? An OR conditional is more forgiving than AND. An OR could be true if just one of them is true, correct?

Comment: Yes, but for your code to work both conditions must be true therefore the connective is conjunction.

Comment: Is this due to the internal properties of the properties of an array and how the typeof operator works on undefined? I guess it's just working differently than what I would expect in something like C/C++ and I'm curious as to why.

Comment: No, its just that you have two conditions `A` and `B` and the body of the `if` assumes that both are true i.e. that `A && B` is true. As such that has to be the condition of the `if`.

Comment: Ah, ok. I would assume that the inner condition would still return 'undefined', so my assumption is wrong on how it worked. Thank you.

Comment: The inner condition still could be false as none of the prior conditions imply its truth.

Comment: I woke up this morning, thought about this problem, understood the problem and solution, and realized how silly my problem is. There are points in your programming career where you are completely surprised at the little, simple things you miss, thinking instead that you're missing something more complex. These moments can also be very depressing. "I studied Computer Science for all those years to overlook something this simple?!" You question your life. Where you've been. Where you're going. and for what? One can be depressed or be humbled. It's best to be humbled and keep learning humility.

Comment: I should probably vote to close the question, unless I can edit my original question to something more pertinent to the actual problem. It's mortifying when you miss such a simple mistake like this. May my original question and problem be forever lost in forgetfulness and my shame be with me no more. :-)